# Migrate users from SQL to openLdap

Tags: mysql, ldap, migration, openldap

Anyone could recommend on fast effective technique for migrating users from SQL database(MYSQL) to OpenLdap?

Comment: If you don't have huge numbers of users it doesn't really matter how fast it is. You don't state what programming language you are contemplating.

Comment: how did you fixed ?  i want to migrate mysql user , their roles into LDAP. ?